# Unmarshaling nested string slice into float32

Tags: go

I have a json file like

```
[{"sequence": 12188764183, "bids": [["10167.66", "0.91182063"], ["10167.65", "0.016"], ["10164.46", "0.35778977"], ["10164.45", "5.714"], ["10164.01", "0.2"], ["10163.5", "0.01"], ["10163.49", "4.597"], ["10162.19", "0.761"], ["10162.17", "3.999"], ["10162.16", "2.4"], ["10161.93", "0.024"], ["10161.31", "0.00771652"], ["10160.07", "0.27"], ["10160", "3.47279335"], ["10159.99", "0.0011"], ["10159.88", "1.5"], ["10159", "0.20869106"], ["10158.79", "0.04"], ["10158.67", "4.5"], ["10158.03", "0.004"], ["10157.59", "0.725"], ["10156.99", "0.7893"], ["10156.98", "1.6"], ["10155", "0.1"], ["10154.52", "0.29542"], ["10154.15", "2.17"], ["10153.59", "0.3"], ["10151.58", "1.4055"], ["10151.2", "0.123"], ["10150", "0.77685084"], ["10149.99", "0.00104364"], ["10149.69", "1.85"], ["10148.66", "0.19707"], ["10148.65", "0.29554"], ["10148.27", "8.1"], ["10148.17", "0.084409"], ["10146.54", "1.88"], ["10145.74", "0.1721"], ["10145.72", "0.29554"], ["10145", "0.005"], ["10143.94", "1.3"], ["10143.89", "0.003"], ["10142.79", "0.29554"], ["10141.57", "1.6"], ["10141.5", "0.01154149"], ["10141", "0.005"], ["10140", "0.1"], ["10138.88", "1.066"], ["10138.37", "0.07871087"], ["10137.63", "0.79331873"]], "asks": [["10167.67", "0.04447368"], ["10167.72", "0.001"], ["10168.6", "0.2"], ["10168.85", "2"], ["10169.19", "0.29501"], ["10170", "1.19"], ["10170.02", "3.33049225"], ["10172.12", "0.29496"], ["10172.87", "4.5"], ["10173.57", "0.123"], ["10173.64", "4.555"], ["10175.05", "0.29484"], ["10175.18", "4.4"], ["10176.04", "0.55440618"], ["10176.05", "4.1"], ["10176.43", "1.04"], ["10177.98", "0.29478"], ["10178.35", "4.1"], ["10178.37", "0.00463633"], ["10178.79", "1.3"], ["10178.94", "0.01"], ["10179", "0.04"], ["10179.07", "1"], ["10179.82", "0.004"], ["10179.84", "0.001"], ["10180", "1.50558876"], ["10180.02", "0.001"], ["10180.3", "8.1"], ["10180.91", "0.007"], ["10180.92", "0.29482"], ["10181.07", "2.2"], ["10181.67", "0.68359706"], ["10181.71", "0.0015"], ["10182.15", "0.01"], ["10182.41", "0.02"], ["10182.45", "0.004"], ["10182.54", "0.7766"], ["10183.82", "1.9"], ["10183.85", "0.29482"], ["10184", "0.001"], ["10184.31", "0.001"], ["10184.52", "0.0049976"], ["10184.74", "0.00231"], ["10185", "3.17362533"], ["10185.19", "2.5"], ["10185.37", "0.01"], ["10185.68", "1.1"], ["10185.82", "0.002"], ["10185.87", "0.04"], ["10186.41", "0.1721"]], "timestamp": "2020-02-10 00:00:07.665713"},{"sequence": 12188766096, "bids": [["10167.75", "0.2"], ["10167.74", "0.2"], ["10167.72", "5.98300001"], ["10167.71", "0.144"], ["10167.67", "4.1"], ["10167.66", "2.24"], ["10167.65", "0.016"], ["10165.59", "0.35773702"], ["10165.58", "4.036"], ["10164.46", "0.01"], ["10164.45", "5.714"], ["10164.3", "2.2"], ["10163.48", "0.27"], ["10163.47", "4.5"], ["10163.09", "0.024"], ["10162.19", "0.761"], ["10162.17", "3.999"], ["10162.16", "2.4"], ["10161.31", "0.00771652"], ["10161.28", "0.7959"], ["10160.56", "0.04"], ["10160", "3.47279335"], ["10159.99", "0.0011"], ["10159.88", "1.5"], ["10159", "0.20869106"], ["10158.03", "0.004"], ["10157.45", "0.29534"], ["10156.98", "1.6"], ["10156.81", "0.3"], ["10155", "0.1"], ["10154.54", "8.1"], ["10154.52", "0.29542"], ["10154.15", "2.17"], ["10153.59", "0.3"], ["10151.81", "0.197009"], ["10151.58", "1.4055"], ["10150", "0.77685084"], ["10149.99", "0.00104364"], ["10149.69", "1.85"], ["10149", "0.084409"], ["10148.65", "0.29554"], ["10146.54", "1.88"], ["10145.74", "0.1721"], ["10145.72", "0.29554"], ["10145", "0.005"], ["10143.94", "1.3"], ["10143.89", "0.003"], ["10142.79", "0.29554"], ["10141.5", "0.01154149"], ["10141.23", "0.171076"]], "asks": [["10170", "1.18190554"], ["10170.02", "3.33049225"], ["10173.64", "4.555"], ["10174.2", "0.2"], ["10175.05", "0.29484"], ["10175.18", "4.1"], ["10176.04", "0.55440618"], ["10176.05", "4.1"], ["10177.4", "1"], ["10177.46", "1.12603391"], ["10177.67", "4.5"], ["10177.98", "0.29478"], ["10178.35", "4.1"], ["10178.37", "0.001"], ["10178.79", "1.3"], ["10178.94", "0.01"], ["10179", "0.04"], ["10179.21", "0.3"], ["10179.82", "0.004"], ["10179.84", "0.001"], ["10180", "1.50558876"], ["10180.02", "0.001"], ["10180.8", "0.83971639"], ["10180.91", "0.007"], ["10180.92", "0.29482"], ["10181.07", "2.2"], ["10181.67", "0.68359706"], ["10181.71", "0.0015"], ["10182.15", "0.01"], ["10182.41", "0.02"], ["10182.45", "0.004"], ["10183.82", "1.9"], ["10183.85", "0.29482"], ["10184", "0.001"], ["10184.31", "0.001"], ["10184.52", "0.0049976"], ["10184.74", "0.00231"], ["10185", "3.17362533"], ["10185.19", "2.5"], ["10185.37", "0.01"], ["10185.68", "1.1"], ["10185.82", "0.002"], ["10185.87", "0.04"], ["10186.41", "0.1721"], ["10186.54", "0.0015"], ["10186.6", "8.1"], ["10186.78", "0.29482"], ["10186.97", "0.008"], ["10187", "0.15"], ["10187.21", "0.02041222"]], "timestamp": "2020-02-10 00:00:17.702649"},{"sequence": 12188769568, "bids": [["10174.75", "0.016"], ["10174.39", "2"], ["10174.38", "0.2"], ["10170.66", "4.5"], ["10170", "0.35758237"], ["10169.99", "7.825"], ["10169.85", "0.024"], ["10169.61", "1.74"], ["10168.53", "0.88915013"], ["10167.68", "0.40823914"], ["10167.67", "36.80084511"], ["10167.66", "0.036"], ["10167.64", "0.686"], ["10167.5", "0.04"], ["10167.48", "1.8"], ["10166.42", "0.3"], ["10165.58", "4.036"], ["10164.3", "2.2"], ["10163.33", "0.8008"], ["10163.04", "0.579"], ["10162.17", "3.999"], ["10162.16", "2.4"], ["10161.73", "8.1"], ["10161.31", "0.00771652"], ["10160.53", "0.119"], ["10160.39", "0.196843"], ["10160.38", "0.29522"], ["10160", "3.47279335"], ["10159.99", "0.0011"], ["10159.88", "1.5"], ["10159", "0.20869106"], ["10158.03", "0.004"], ["10157.45", "0.29534"], ["10156.98", "1.6"], ["10155", "0.1"], ["10154.52", "0.29542"], ["10154.25", "0.92941369"], ["10154.15", "2.17"], ["10153.1", "1.20082209"], ["10152.11", "0.1668"], ["10151.73", "2.1"], ["10151.58", "0.2955"], ["10150", "0.77685084"], ["10149.99", "0.00104364"], ["10149.97", "0.084409"], ["10149.2", "1.9"], ["10148.65", "0.29554"], ["10148.11", "1.066"], ["10145", "0.005"], ["10144.74", "14.73320213"]], "asks": [["10175.48", "0.46015637"], ["10175.49", "4"], ["10177.35", "6.1"], ["10177.4", "6.1"], ["10178.85", "1.00995404"], ["10178.94", "0.01"], ["10178.97", "0.2"], ["10179", "0.04"], ["10179.09", "0.06477417"], ["10179.82", "0.004"], ["10179.84", "0.001"], ["10180", "1.50558876"], ["10180.02", "0.001"], ["10180.91", "0.007"], ["10181.67", "0.68359706"], ["10181.71", "0.0015"], ["10181.76", "0.00520665"], ["10182.15", "0.01"], ["10182.41", "0.02"], ["10182.45", "0.004"], ["10183.39", "1.83"], ["10183.85", "0.29461"], ["10184", "0.001"], ["10184.31", "0.001"], ["10184.52", "0.0049976"], ["10184.74", "0.00231"], ["10184.87", "4.5"], ["10185", "3.17362533"], ["10185.16", "0.3"], ["10185.19", "2.5"], ["10185.37", "0.01"], ["10185.8", "1.62"], ["10185.82", "0.002"], ["10185.87", "0.04"], ["10186.18", "0.92941369"], ["10186.52", "0.3575008"], ["10186.54", "0.0015"], ["10186.78", "0.29482"], ["10186.97", "0.008"], ["10187", "0.15"], ["10188", "0.02"], ["10188.39", "1.69"], ["10188.4", "0.0049957"], ["10188.59", "0.01"], ["10188.85", "0.3"], ["10189", "0.56"], ["10189.29", "0.001"], ["10189.4", "0.01559953"], ["10189.95", "0.00245026"], ["10190", "0.05726459"]], "timestamp": "2020-02-10 00:00:27.738108"}]
```

I would like to have the inner bids arrays converted to `float32` during unmarshalling. Found a bunch of answers on here. Some involve the use of ",string" tag. Although, it is not clear how to use that for nested slices. I saw an example in golang docs that uses `json.RawMessage` to unmarhsal into unmarshaled json. Anyhow, I would really appreciate your pointers here. Right now I have this, which is not what I want

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// DataPointCoinbase - defines the ob coinbase data point
type DataPointCoinbase struct {
    Sequence  int32           `json:"sequence"`
    Bids      [][]json.Number `json:"bids"`
    Asks      [][]json.Number `json:"asks"`
    Timestamp string          `json:"timestamp"`
}

// ParseCoinbase - parses coinbase orderbook file
func main() {
    data := []byte(`[
    {
    "sequence": 12188764183, 
    "bids": [
       ["10167.66", "0.91182063"], 
       ["10167.65", "0.016"], 
       ["10164.46", "0.35778977"]
    ], 
    "asks": [
       ["10167.66", "0.91182063"], 
       ["10167.65", "0.016"], 
       ["10164.46", "0.35778977"]
    ], 
    "timestamp": "2020-02-10 00:00:07.665713"}
    ]`)
    var dataPoints []DataPointCoinbase

    json.Unmarshal(data, &dataPoints)

    fmt.Println(dataPoints)
}
```

Comment: The programme would halt, if there was an error, no? And it doesn't. (when I use [][2]uint16). It just fills out everything with zero

Comment: always check for all errors. https://play.golang.org/p/AZeB9h8MpFR

Comment: as your input numbers are quoted you are kind of stuck with json.Number, or a custom version of it, so you probably should consider https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Float64 in that version, with fixed json encoding of floating numbers, https://play.golang.org/p/wNH4AkQmlSN, there is no problem to define the struct with float64s right away.

Comment: I could write a regex pattern that would unquote the numbers, and then use float32 (if that would work). But is that really the best way to go about it...

Comment: you ceertainly dont want to apply a regexp on your input. If you are really sure a float32 is the right type, go for a custom type that implements a custom unmarshaler. see those previous questions for implementations examples (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+custom+unmarshaler). In your case strip the quotes before parsing the float.

Comment: My main objective is to fit as much of the data as possible in memory, I thought that float32 is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be, you can write helper methods to do the conversions at each
depth of the input. The only difference in your case is in addition to doing
type assertion, at the endpoint we also have to parse the string. Here are
example methods:

```
package main
import "fmt"
type Slice []interface{}
type Map map[string]interface{}

func (a Slice) A(n int) Slice {
   return a[n].([]interface{})
}

func (a Slice) M(n int) Map {
   return a[n].(map[string]interface{})
}

func (m Map) A(s string) Slice {
   return m[s].([]interface{})
}

func (a Slice) N(n int) float32 {
   var f float32
   fmt.Sscan(a[n].(string), &f)
   return f
}
```

and example usage:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   o, e := os.Open("a.json")
   if e != nil {
      log.Fatal(e)
   }
   a := Slice{}
   json.NewDecoder(o).Decode(&a)
   n := a.M(0).A("bids").A(0).N(0)
   fmt.Println(n == 10167.66)
}
```

You can write further methods as needed, if your JSON is different.